# I ran out of characters for my Answer... what to do?

Tags: discussion, answers

I am working on a monstrosity of an answer, reviewing the various splats of Werewolf the Apocalypse [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/133398/30306).

All worked well till I tried to add something about the Nuwisha.... at which point this little message appeared in red under the window, which also was framed red now:

> Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 30357.

And... I am just about 6 and a half splats (got to reread Kitsune) out from finishing this...

What should I do?! 30k characters is nowhere near enough to work out AND provide the quotes, but the quotes are to the most part essential as this is a matter of *proving* the points.

I estimate at this moment that I'd need about... maybe 4k characters to fill in the blanks (Corax, Gurahl, Ratkin, Mokolé, Ananasi, Nagah, Beast Courts) and then possibly another 4k to get through the player's guides. So, about a third of another answer's space...

For the immediate moment, I resorted to adding further research to a separated answer, to get below the 30k threshold and still share the results, but it tastes 
funny... then changed mind and deleted the extra answer to work in a commentable [google-doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BNmNhS84AG3BubLOwGnQkFQNXkpyW8u5f0gcWdibqyc/edit?usp=sharing) instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Be more concise.

Some of your quote blocks are quite large. You have the option of paraphrasing your source or providing inline quotes: *‘The garou say that “candy canes are bad”’* — as opposed to a much larger quote to the same effect.

You only get 30,000 characters, so use them wisely.

I've got some conciseness edits I could make in an hour or two.

Comment: if you could... thank you I am better at adding new stuff than revising... :/ I had also thought about splitting Garou and others... but that too tastes foul... so... resorted to Google-Doc for the moment... https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BNmNhS84AG3BubLOwGnQkFQNXkpyW8u5f0gcWdibqyc/edit?usp=sharing