# Witty, clever & funny: let's collect the bounty's messages!

Tags: discussion, bounty, just-for-fun

In the past, several bounties have been offered, both for making questions attract more answers and for rewarding already existent answers (which are the actual aims of bounties).

Beside the default ones, some users started to write witty messages for the bounty: since I truly believe that a lot of them  contained clever puns or were very funny, I suggest to collect them here, in imperishable memory.

Comment: For spelunkers, we mods have no particular visibility on expired/awarded bounties' messages--so if you're looking for one you remember we have no special tools to help. But the query described in [this meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291433/311001) would pull the comment from any bounty, if you know the question it was on.

Comment: [This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/revision/1076648/1887998/list-of-my-bounties-including-the-bounty-comment) allows you to search by user ID. [Here's my list](https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/revision/1681237/2046029/list-of-my-bounties-including-the-bounty-comment), there's some goofy ones in there.

Comment: @nitsua60 Didn't know it! Actually, I recall  some messages but I don't remember on which questions they were put on...

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I must admit that yours were the inspiration of this question! But I did not know that using such queries allows to recover all the messages

Comment: I am not sure this collection is a good idea. The presence of this hall of fame incentivises people to begin using their bounty messages specifically to seek entry into this hall of fame, rather than just writing the bounty messages they otherwise would. That's ... possibly a detrimental effect. I would advocate just letting the good ones be fun & ephemeral jokes that will vanish away again soon after.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because establishing a bounty message hall of fame will have a detrimental effect & incentivise behaviour that is not necessarily desirable for people to pursue.

Comment: @doppelgreener I understand your concern, but since you do not get any badge, rep bonus or any other gamification from the SE site by entering in this hall of fame, I don't think that there will be any disruption in the bounty message entries. Anyway, the [just-for-fun] tag requires that the mods have to check if the question is good for meta: if they decide that it is not so, that' s fine for me!

Comment: @Eddymage The just-for-fun tag says that the mods _and community_ must approve the post. In fact, it says they must approve it _before_ posting, which didn't happen. In any case: here I am, part of the community, voicing my disapproval and explaining my concern. This hall of fame is still a form of incentive; I am not talking about system incentives.

Comment: @doppelgreener You're right, I skipped "the community" when I read the description. Indeed, I thought that before being published this question would have been in a sort of "embargo", waiting for mods' approval. Anyway, I understand your concerns, I will  let the community decide via the closing/leave–open votes.

Comment: While I was enthusiastic about the idea at first, this kind of hall of fame will indeed push some people to "go for the funny" when making bounty messages, which, while it is nice and fun once in a while, defeats the point if it happens too often. So as much as I like the original idea, it doesn't seem like it'd work with how bounty messages are supposed to be, and how that would influence them.

Answer (score 9):

#### Reminiscents from *Arabian Nights*

Thomas Markov offered 100 Rep Points on the question [How many creatures fit on a Carpet of Flying during combat?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/202734/63061) and disrupted our childhood memories:

> Sorry Aladdin. According to the rules of D&D, you unfortunately cannot show me the world.

Comment: I have a different perspective of what the right answer there is but that does not detract at all from the bounty message being very cool. He had another nice one on a bounty he made for me (something with Magubliet's blood feast) but I think one cannot see them any more once they are awarded.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin "GROODY MAKE GOOD ANSWER. GIVE GROODY 200 LEGS OF DEER FOR MAGLUBIYET'S BLOOD FEAST.", for [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/202252/62294)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Yes that was it. I actually did eat blood sausage in honor of it the eveing it was awarded :)

Answer (score 7):

#### Precious spices from the East India Company

After a long journey in the mystic lands of India, Thomas Markov brought me some spice for an answer to [Does every magic rod, wand, crystal, orb, and staff count as an arcane focus?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59951/63061)

> I'm awarding 500 Markov's Salt & Vinegar internet points to Eddymage's answer for the several keen observations made about the magic items from the more recent book releases. Warning: Internet points manufactured in a facility that also produces reddit karma.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than sit and laugh at [my own jokes](https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/revision/1681237/2046029/list-of-my-bounties-including-the-bounty-comment), I'd like to put forward two posts I gave bounties to because I thought they were tremendously funny.

#### "I wanty the game"

From the early days of the site, myxzplk provides [guidance for finding other players](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/4284/62294) that has stood the test of time. The guidance is worthy of a bounty, but one phrase insightfully caricatures people who just fling their desire for players out into the universe expecting the game to come to them; it was for that phrase I offered this bounty message:

> 100 internet points to mxyzplk for this beautiful piece of English prose: "I wanty the game".

Four words, one of them spelled incorrectly, perfectly captures so many of the low effort "looking for group" posts I have sifted through across various forums and brick-and-mortar shop bulletin boards.

#### "Refusing to play or refusing to allow the game to be played by others is not a playstyle."

The question [How to deal with a player who says no all the time?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/163377/62294) presents a tale of a problem player who apparently doesn't actually want to play the game, declining to bite on any of the plot hooks and content opportunities presented by the DM. Upper_Case provides a [perfect diagnosis](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/163384/62294) of the problem, for which I gave a bounty with message:

> Refusing to play or refusing to allow the game to be played by others is not a playstyle.

While we [embrace a plurality of playstyles](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5174/can-we-affirm-that-rpg-se-embraces-a-plurality-of-playstyles) on this site, Upper_Case helpfully points out that refusing to play the game and impeding the play for others is not a playstyle, so naturally, we shouldn't have to tolerate such silliness at the table of play. I don't know what it was, but something about the candidness of this statement gave me quite the chuckle.

Answer (score 4):

### Honoring the limited verbal skills of Hobgoblins

> GROODY MAKE GOOD ANSWER. GIVE GROODY 200 LEGS OF DEER FOR MAGLUBIYET'S BLOOD FEAST.

For [Does the Wristpocket spell allow a bead from the Chronurgy wizard's Arcane Abeyance feature to last forever?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/200790/does-the-wristpocket-spell-allow-a-bead-from-the-chronurgy-wizards-arcane-abeya/202252#202252) in reference of the screen name awarded to
[Groody the Hobgoblin](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/users/75095/groody-the-hobgoblin).

Comment: What happened to the fifty-odd deer without legs? Is Thomas Markov stealing the best parts?

Comment: @Phoenices They were kept alive and taught to swim like fish.

Answer (score 4):

I very fondly remember this one from when I asked a question, then delved in to dig through all the books myself after I had gotten a few rather... opinionated answer to a very delicate question about how [the game itself presents their splats to stand towards LBGTQ-topics](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/133398/30306):

> [Trish's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/133398/2100) is the kind of things that we should show new comers to aim for. It deservers more recognition. - [Sardathrion - against SE abuse](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/2100)

For an answer that **[broke the limit of the text field](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8504/i-ran-out-of-characters-for-my-answer-what-to-do)**